# How to vectorise row function to speed up the process significantly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, vectorization

I am trying this function:

```
df.head():
    runtime       match_datetime  dow  month    country                        league       home_team              away_team                   team  team_type  home_odds  draw_odds  away_odds  home_score  away_score  predicted_home_score  predicted_away_score  predicted_home_score_n  predicted_away_score_n  predicted_draw  predicted_o1.5  predicted_u1.5  predicted_btts  predicted_btts_n  btts  predicted_bttso2.5  predicted_bttso2.5_n  bttso2.5  predicted_bttsu2.5  predicted_bttsu2.5_n  bttsu2.5  predicted_o2.5  predicted_o2.5_n  o2.5  predicted_u2.5  predicted_u2.5_n  u2.5  predicted_o4  predicted_u4  score_difference  total_score result  predicted_score_difference  predicted_total_score predicted_result result_match  count  win_weight  dnb_weight  o_1_5_weight  o_2_5_weight  u_2_5_weight  btts_weight  btts_o_2_5_weight  btts_u_2_5_weight  u_4_5_weight                selection_n selection_match_n
0       NaN  2023-08-05 03:00:00    5      8    Austria             Regionalliga West         SC Imst          Dornbirner SV                SC Imst  home_team       1.67       4.30       3.95           1           3              2.210979              1.329973                2.235496                1.341948        0.207470        0.842816        0.148767        0.594604          0.618518     1            0.534845              0.536766         1            0.090211              0.083080         0        0.665690          0.697917     1        0.335880          0.291228     0      0.281594      0.530389                 2            4   away                    0.881006               3.540952             home     no match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)             match
1       NaN  2023-08-05 03:00:00    5      8    Austria             Regionalliga West         SC Imst          Dornbirner SV          Dornbirner SV  away_team       1.67       4.30       3.95           1           3              2.210979              1.329973                2.235496                1.341948        0.207470        0.842816        0.148767        0.594604          0.618518     1            0.534845              0.536766         1            0.090211              0.083080         0        0.665690          0.697917     1        0.335880          0.291228     0      0.281594      0.530389                 2            4   away                    0.881006               3.540952             home     no match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)             match
2       NaN  2023-08-05 00:00:00    5      8    Lebanon                Premier League         Tadamon             Al Ghazieh                Tadamon  home_team       2.18       3.26       3.09           2           0              1.343957              1.114911                1.364438                1.130438        0.282644        0.714166        0.278891        0.527975          0.531042     0            0.402473              0.397920         0            0.130483              0.131940         0        0.468953          0.477249     0        0.551530          0.529926     1      0.110470      0.743486                 2            2   home                    0.229046               2.458867             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
3       NaN  2023-08-05 00:00:00    5      8    Lebanon                Premier League         Tadamon             Al Ghazieh             Al Ghazieh  away_team       2.18       3.26       3.09           2           0              1.343957              1.114911                1.364438                1.130438        0.282644        0.714166        0.278891        0.527975          0.531042     0            0.402473              0.397920         0            0.130483              0.131940         0        0.468953          0.477249     0        0.551530          0.529926     1      0.110470      0.743486                 2            2   home                    0.229046               2.458867             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
4       NaN  2023-08-03 00:30:00    3      8    Romania                  Romanian Cup     Calimanesti                 Horezu            Calimanesti  home_team       2.08       3.33       3.19           1           0              1.478548              1.121277                1.471412                1.159540        0.127597        0.706101        0.286398        0.509088          0.516939     0            0.409120              0.435302         0            0.106371              0.067940         0        0.503515          0.532446     0        0.486215          0.480485     1      0.128372      0.752334                 1            1   home                    0.357271               2.599825             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
5       NaN  2023-08-03 00:30:00    3      8    Romania                  Romanian Cup     Calimanesti                 Horezu            Calimanesti  home_team       2.08       3.33       3.19           1           0              1.461488              1.149807                1.436531                1.175677        0.150561        0.723969        0.285449        0.515130          0.519419     0            0.410945              0.423630         0            0.109881              0.084864         0        0.509575          0.517720     0        0.512752          0.481573     1      0.122197      0.744140                 1            1   home                    0.311681               2.611295             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
6       NaN  2023-08-03 00:30:00    3      8    Romania                  Romanian Cup     Calimanesti                 Horezu                 Horezu  away_team       2.08       3.33       3.19           1           0              1.461488              1.149807                1.436531                1.175677        0.150561        0.723969        0.285449        0.515130          0.519419     0            0.410945              0.423630         0            0.109881              0.084864         0        0.509575          0.517720     0        0.512752          0.481573     1      0.122197      0.744140                 1            1   home                    0.311681               2.611295             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
7       NaN  2023-08-03 00:30:00    3      8    Romania                  Romanian Cup     Calimanesti                 Horezu                 Horezu  away_team       2.08       3.33       3.19           1           0              1.478548              1.121277                1.471412                1.159540        0.127597        0.706101        0.286398        0.509088          0.516939     0            0.409120              0.435302         0            0.106371              0.067940         0        0.503515          0.532446     0        0.486215          0.480485     1      0.128372      0.752334                 1            1   home                    0.357271               2.599825             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
8       NaN  2023-08-01 02:30:00    1      8     Russia                Premier League  Spartak Moscow                Baltika         Spartak Moscow  home_team       1.46       4.78       6.60           2           1              2.265749              0.857737                2.220995                0.874260        0.171777        0.782740        0.201593        0.514003          0.536349     1            0.456050              0.456741         1            0.066444              0.050176         0        0.607440          0.616507     1        0.378635          0.382310     0      0.214583      0.636758                 1            3   home                    1.408011               3.123486             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4  W & BTTS O 2.5 (untested)             match
9       NaN  2023-08-01 02:30:00    1      8     Russia                Premier League  Spartak Moscow                Baltika                Baltika  away_team       1.46       4.78       6.60           2           1              2.265749              0.857737                2.220995                0.874260        0.171777        0.782740        0.201593        0.514003          0.536349     1            0.456050              0.456741         1            0.066444              0.050176         0        0.607440          0.616507     1        0.378635          0.382310     0      0.214583      0.636758                 1            3   home                    1.408011               3.123486             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4  W & BTTS O 2.5 (untested)             match
10      NaN  2023-07-31 01:30:00    0      7    Hungary            NB III - Northwest   Balatonfuredi             Gyirmot II             Gyirmot II  away_team       1.95       3.86       3.20           1           0              1.901776              1.347961                1.861217                1.355588        0.211803        0.830625        0.178242        0.620196          0.629087     0            0.536158              0.549040         0            0.092978              0.095712         0        0.620287          0.600810     0        0.387408          0.344317     1      0.232697      0.603490                 1            1   home                    0.553815               3.249738             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
11      NaN  2023-07-31 01:30:00    0      7    Hungary            NB III - Northwest   Balatonfuredi             Gyirmot II             Gyirmot II  away_team       1.95       3.86       3.20           1           0              1.791491              1.375635                1.857171                1.310303        0.209078        0.805252        0.190352        0.620355          0.613795     0            0.510595              0.528348         0            0.087528              0.087454         0        0.609982          0.631811     0        0.373315          0.370837     1      0.218271      0.618277                 1            1   home                    0.415857               3.167126             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
12      NaN  2023-07-31 01:30:00    0      7    Hungary            NB III - Northwest   Balatonfuredi             Gyirmot II          Balatonfuredi  home_team       1.95       3.86       3.20           1           0              1.901776              1.347961                1.861217                1.355588        0.211803        0.830625        0.178242        0.620196          0.629087     0            0.536158              0.549040         0            0.092978              0.095712         0        0.620287          0.600810     0        0.387408          0.344317     1      0.232697      0.603490                 1            1   home                    0.553815               3.249738             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
13      NaN  2023-07-31 01:30:00    0      7    Hungary            NB III - Northwest   Balatonfuredi             Gyirmot II          Balatonfuredi  home_team       1.95       3.86       3.20           1           0              1.791491              1.375635                1.857171                1.310303        0.209078        0.805252        0.190352        0.620355          0.613795     0            0.510595              0.528348         0            0.087528              0.087454         0        0.609982          0.631811     0        0.373315          0.370837     1      0.218271      0.618277                 1            1   home                    0.415857               3.167126             home        match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
14      NaN  2023-07-30 04:30:00    6      7  Argentina                     Primera C    Puerto Nuevo     San Martin Burzaco           Puerto Nuevo  home_team       3.15       2.89       2.35           2           2              0.938791              1.181563                1.037248                1.133719        0.330187        0.633157        0.376882        0.417566          0.430760     1            0.282211              0.320710         1            0.137969              0.108859         0        0.360314          0.394837     1        0.624053          0.626919     0      0.056253      0.823315                 0            4   draw                    0.242772               2.120355             away     no match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4            BTTS (untested)             match
15      NaN  2023-07-30 04:30:00    6      7  Argentina                     Primera C    Puerto Nuevo     San Martin Burzaco     San Martin Burzaco  away_team       3.15       2.89       2.35           2           2              0.938791              1.181563                1.037248                1.133719        0.330187        0.633157        0.376882        0.417566          0.430760     1            0.282211              0.320710         1            0.137969              0.108859         0        0.360314          0.394837     1        0.624053          0.626919     0      0.056253      0.823315                 0            4   draw                    0.242772               2.120355             away     no match      2         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4            BTTS (untested)             match
16      NaN  2023-07-30 00:00:00    6      7     Russia  FNL 2 - Division B - Group 1          Biolog       Dynamo Stavropol       Dynamo Stavropol  away_team       1.79       3.44       4.10           1           0              1.494784              0.918835                1.532657                0.914463        0.267865        0.695971        0.297255        0.490663          0.487278     0            0.358992              0.371660         0            0.119869              0.123422         0        0.445312          0.441919     0        0.549941          0.560354     1      0.106378      0.776750                 1            1   home                    0.575949               2.413619             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
17      NaN  2023-07-30 00:00:00    6      7     Russia  FNL 2 - Division B - Group 3           Kvant         Arsenal Tula 2                  Kvant  home_team       2.23       3.40       2.79           0           0              1.372409              1.252680                1.439577                1.252028        0.267299        0.710040        0.282394        0.522105          0.533618     0            0.403247              0.416162         0            0.119348              0.111886         0        0.492482          0.501382     0        0.517629          0.510572     1      0.127235      0.756128                 0            0   draw                    0.119729               2.625089             home     no match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
18      NaN  2023-07-30 00:00:00    6      7     Russia  FNL 2 - Division B - Group 1          Biolog       Dynamo Stavropol                 Biolog  home_team       1.79       3.44       4.10           1           0              1.494784              0.918835                1.532657                0.914463        0.267865        0.695971        0.297255        0.490663          0.487278     0            0.358992              0.371660         0            0.119869              0.123422         0        0.445312          0.441919     0        0.549941          0.560354     1      0.106378      0.776750                 1            1   home                    0.575949               2.413619             home        match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
19      NaN  2023-07-30 00:00:00    6      7     Russia  FNL 2 - Division B - Group 3           Kvant         Arsenal Tula 2         Arsenal Tula 2  away_team       2.23       3.40       2.79           0           0              1.372409              1.252680                1.439577                1.252028        0.267299        0.710040        0.282394        0.522105          0.533618     0            0.403247              0.416162         0            0.119348              0.111886         0        0.492482          0.501382     0        0.517629          0.510572     1      0.127235      0.756128                 0            0   draw                    0.119729               2.625089             home     no match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match
20      NaN  2023-07-30 00:00:00    6      7     Russia  FNL 2 - Division B - Group 2    Znamya Truda              Baltika 2              Baltika 2  away_team       2.04       3.40       3.25           1           1              1.496329              1.064672                1.550025                1.101253        0.277913        0.713811        0.271416        0.534334          0.551954     1            0.406223              0.411813         0            0.121034              0.136186         1        0.482891          0.447424     0        0.554452          0.511082     1      0.118090      0.758297                 0            2   draw                    0.431657               2.561002             home     no match      1         1.1         0.7           3.2           0.4           0.4          0.4                0.4                0.4           0.4           O 2.5 (untested)          no match





df.shape: (2437086, 39)
```

I have a row function to update a column as:

```
def selection_update_n(row):
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS O 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS O 2.5 (untested)'):
        if row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        elif (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0) and row["total_score"] < 3:
            row["btts_o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
        elif row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0:
            row["btts_o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        if row["home_score"] > 0 and row["away_score"] > 0:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        elif (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0):
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
            row["btts_weight"] += 0.02
    elif row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & BTTS (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0):
        row["btts_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 2.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        if row["total_score"] > 2:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        elif row["total_score"] < 3:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
            row["o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    elif row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 2.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and row["total_score"] < 3:
        row["o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 1.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 1.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        if row["total_score"] > 1:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        else:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
            row["o_1_5_weight"] += 0.02
    elif row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 1.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & O 1.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and row["total_score"] < 2:
        row["o_1_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & U 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & U 2.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        if row["total_score"] < 3:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        else:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
            row["u_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    elif row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'W & U 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'W & U 2.5 (untested)') and row["result_match"] == 'match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and row["total_score"] > 2:
        row["u_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == "W & U 4.5" or row["selection_n"] == "W & U 4.5 (untested)") and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        if row["total_score"] < 5:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
        else:
            row["win_weight"] += 0.02
            row["u_4_5_weight"] += 0.02
    elif row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == "W & U 4.5" or row["selection_n"] == "W & U 4.5 (untested)") and row["result_match"] == 'match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and row["total_score"] > 4:
        row["u_4_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == "W" or row["selection_n"] == "W (untested)") and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        row["win_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == "W" or row["selection_n"] == "W (untested)") and row["result_match"] == 'no match' and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw':
        row["win_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'O 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'O 2.5 (untested)') and row["total_score"] < 3:
        row["o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'BTTS O 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'BTTS O 2.5 (untested)') and (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0 or row["total_score"] < 3):
        row["btts_o_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'BTTS' or row["selection_n"] == 'BTTS (untested)') and (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0):
        row["btts_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'U 2.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'U 2.5 (untested)') and row["total_score"] > 2:
        row["u_2_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == "DNB" or row["selection_n"] == "DNB (untested)") and row["predicted_result"] != 'draw' and (row["result_match"] != 'no match' or row["result"] != 'draw'):
        row["dnb_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'U 4.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'U 4.5 (untested)') and row["total_score"] > 4:
        row["u_4_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'O 1.5 and U 4.5' or row["selection_n"] == 'O 1.5 and U 4.5 (untested)') and (row["total_score"] < 2 or row["total_score"] > 4):
        row["o_1_5_weight"] += 0.02
        row["u_4_5_weight"] += 0.02
    if row["selection_match_n"] == 'no match' and (row["selection_n"] == 'U 2.5 & BTTS' or row["selection_n"] == 'U 2.5 & BTTS (untested)') and (row["home_score"] == 0 or row["away_score"] == 0 or row["total_score"] > 2):
        row["btts_u_2_5_weight"] += 0.0
    return row
```

And then I loop over to update the weights as:

```
start_time = time.time()
df = df.apply(selection_update_n, axis=1)
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Time taken for Applying Selection Update: {end_time - start_time} seconds")


print("Applying Selections Update")
print("Loop to update Selection weights")

loop_counter = 0
while (df["selection_match_n"] == "no match").any():
    start_time = time.time()
    loop_counter += 1
    print(f"Iteration: {loop_counter}")
    df['selection_n'] = df.apply(selection_n, axis=1)
    df = df.apply(selection_update_n, axis=1)
    df['selection_match_n'] = df.apply(selection_match_n, axis=1)
    print('Count of Selection: no_match rows:', (df["selection_match_n"] == "no match").sum())
    # print(df[df['selection_match_n'] == 'no match'])
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken for this iteration: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

Since this is a row function, it takes a lot of time to complete and is not efficent. Is there a way this can be sped up significantly?
A few things I can think of are vectorisation, multi-core processing by using libraries such as `modin`, `swifter` however I am not across those and I keep getting errors.

Comment: this is a good candidate to go on [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Can you also provide a larger example or random generation code for testing and benchmarking?

Comment: Updated dataframe example to maximum allowed here

Comment: Both your `df` and code are incomplete. The `selection_update_n` function accesses the `selection_match_n` column, but no such column exists in your `df`. Also, the `selection_n` and `selection_match_n` functions appear in your code, but their contents are unknown. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, speed is an issue, so the `df` example must be large enough. Use an external site or provide code for random generation. Without it, all we can do is guess, which would end up with an incomplete answer.

Comment: Apologies. updated the correct dataframe example

Comment: Try adding `raw=True` to your `apply` call, it could speed things up as stated in the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Otherwise, using cython might be the go, as described in this example http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html